# Parse email body for certain string using Regex

Tags: regex

Im looking to extract a portion of an email body that provides a unique authentication code each time. This is the format of the string:

Your One Time Verification Code is: 500089

This Verification Code will expire within 30 minutes so please use it soon

What would be the regex expression for extracting the value 500089 in this case? Please note that a whitespace follows the : within the string, and I do not want to extract the whitespace, just the numerical substring.

This is what i have so far: :(.*)

Comment: if you know that it will be always 6 digits, just use `\d{6}`

Comment: @slysyn24 Which regex you need depends on the language that you are using. Could you please provide the language and the code that you have so far ([mcve])